# converting floats to string in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

In Python 3, I got 
a = 4.0000000000000001
b = 4.0000000000000002
since b>a, but while comparing a==b, it returns true and false on other two cases.
I searched it on web and got an idea of converting them to string and then comparing them.
but a=str(a) or repr(a) returns a='4.0' and b='4.0',I know why the repr fun is returning that but i want a='4.000000000000001' and b='4.000000000000002'.Can anyone help me?
// Sorry for the poor english.

Comment: Converting numbers to string to compare is *always* a bad idea. Now for your specific issue, you should learn about how floats work. They cannot represent all values you can type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @spectras So is there any way i can have b>a ?

Comment: Your `a` and `b` are the same value. As `float` does not have enough precision, the tiny bits at the end get truncated and you end up with `a == b == 4.0`. If you need more precision, you'll have to use another type, such as `Decimal`.

Comment: You should show specific code and data. Even disregarding the English, we do not know what it means that you got certain values for a and b since b>a. Were these values calculated? Written in Python source code? Converted from strings? Something else? How can we reproduce exactly the code you are asking about?